# "Строгое" указание символов в столбце

Tags: sql, postgresql

Разрабатываю базу данных для информации о заказчиках. У них есть spec_id специальный идентификатор который генерируется из 10 чисел, но он должен быть не больше и не меньше 10 чисел. Как указать что в столбце должны быть числа и не меньше и не больше 10 чисел в СУБД Postgresql?

Comment: см  `CHECK` - https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.5/ddl-constraints

Comment: @СергейМишин  (таблицу создал age int CHECK (age >= 18) и 17 число не допускает, а если мне нужно минимум 5 чисел, я должен указать >= 10000? или как?

Comment: Ноли в начале идентификатора допустимы: `00001`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да идет от 0000000001 и до 9999999999 где 9999999999 включительно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уж определитесь, вы говорите о строке - и тогда строку вам и необходимо хранить и проверять

```
field char(10) not null check(char_length(field) = 10)
```

Плюс ограничение на вводимые символы. Соседний ответ @alexander-petrov хорошо для этого подойдёт сразу и для ограничения длины и введённых символов.

Такой `char(10)` займёт 11 байт.

Либо вы хотите хранить числовое значение. Но для чисел начальные нули смысла не имеют. Их добавлять вам понадобится при выводе значений из базы. Ограничение в этом случае будет

```
field bigint not null check(field >= 0 and field < 1e10)
```

Либо

```
field numeric(10) not null check(field >= 0 and field < 1e10)
```

Даже не знаю что из них лучше, bigint с постоянной шириной в 8 байт или numeric, занимающий от 5 до 9 байт в этом диапазоне. Наверное bigint будет интереснее как простой тип данных. `int`, который, вы в комментариях упомянули, для вашей задачи будет недостаточен, покрывает только чуть больше 1/5 требуемого диапазона.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t (
  spec_id char(10) check (spec_id >= '0000000001' and spec_id <= '9999999999')
)
```

`char(10)` - задаёт ограничение точно 10 символов.
`check` - задаёт ограничение `[0000000001, 9999999999]`.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ec3f2/1)